# WebAPI respository does not refresh

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Has anyone noticed why the repository in the new WebAPI does not refresh each time a Get request is made?  I don't see anything referencing anything like a cache, however, I don't see the data refreshed every time.  It is very inconsistent.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Which repository are you talking about? Who makes the request? It's really hard to understand what you need without more details.

Comment: You should show your code in here

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and what was happening is that the Database Context was not being disposed after the queries. Check if you're [disposing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27896181/2986652) your objects after the connection.

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13551144/2986652) helped me on disposing and creating a context per request, the same applies for WebAPI's so they don't keep on the memory and refreshes for every request.